# Pretty urls codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the following situation, I have some posts on my website which are access by id, lets say for example
    http://websiteurl.com/posts/see/1
the `posts` controller, has a `see` method which looks for the `id` on the database, lets say it find it and the posts title is "Most amazing photos" , how could i configure the `Route.php` class of codeigniter so that this posts its accessible from an url similar to:

http://websiteurl.com/posts/see/most-amazing-photos-1.html

this posts are created dynamically and they are a lot, so setting one by one manually is not possible.

Thanks!

Comment: `$route['posts/see/most-amazing-photos-1'] = "posts/see/1";` ?

Comment: but in that case it would be for only one url, i have more than 20.000 posts, how can i connect it to the database so that it fetches the title?

Comment: you can try it `$route['posts/see/most-amazing-photos-(:num)'] = "posts/see/$1";`. I don't test this.

Comment: you can check routing in codeigniter help for further options to design your urls.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use regex. Assuming that you will be creating different url tag for each photo you can have something like this in you route.php

```
$route['posts/see/(:any)'] = "posts/see/$1";
```

However it is necessary that you have unique url-tag for each photo otherwise it will be ambiguous to fetch photo from the url-tag.

Have it a go.

Answer (score 0):

The url parameter you would like to achieve is called a `slug`

like `wordpress` does, you can query the POST via its `id` or its slug.

One way to implement this is every time a post is created, you save the slug to the `db`.the slug can be the title of the post or anything readable for SEO. So that everytime a user visits the site, your controller method may prcess the parameter if it is a `slug` or an `id` and continue the query using the given parameters.

then you can set up the routes like:

```
$route['posts/see/(:any)'] = "posts/see/$1";
```